# You * think, they'd be here by now

Tags: conditional-constructions

I came across this question. Although I know the answer, I could not figure out why the other options cannot be used. The answer is "would". Other options are  "could" and " might". Since "could" and "might" can be used in conditional sentences as well, I would like to ask why they would be wrong.

> You _ think, they'd be here by now.

Answer (score 3):

> you would think

precedes an expectation of what you expect should happen, often because it hasn't.

Given your context (what I think was meant), the other words don't mean the same thing.

In:

> You **would** think, they'd be here by now.

the speaker expected them to be there by now, but they haven't arrived for some unexpected reason.

Comment: For example two people, lets say A and B,  wait for their friends to get on the same train at the station. The train leaves 1 pm so A and B would say this before 1 pm. In other words, they would have this talk before their friends miss the train.

Comment: Yes that's correct, and clearly they don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

All three are possible, but *could* and *might* mean something different from *would*, and also are much less common.

> You **would** think they would be here by now

is a hypothetical with an unspoken premise:

> (... assuming that they are still on schedule, that nothing has happened to delay them, that they haven't fallen off a cliff, etc.)

However, while it is grammatical and includes a hypothetical when you logically dissect it, in actual conversation it's more like an idiomatic and slightly more polite variation on

> They **should/ought to** be here by now

Meanwhile because

> You **could/might** think they would be here by now

is a conditional, and since the condition isn't *obvious*, you should explicitly state it.  For example:

> ... if you were to actually think about these kind of things, instead of just about your empty stomach, John.

Comment: For example two people, lets say A and B, wait for their friends to get on the same train at the station. The train leaves 1 pm so A and B would say this before 1 pm. In other words, they would have this talk before their friends miss the train.

Comment: @Mrt  Yes, as I said, it's the same as "They **should** be here by now" -- there is a reasonable expectation of something, which hasn't yet happened, so we ponder why.